# Hibernate Exception when save Model with @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I call hibernate save I face this exception and I don't know how to solve this problem.
In my case, I change the join column from PrimaryKey to another column so I face this exception.
I don't want to save Customer with UnderWriter and I want only to save foreign key.

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

My domain model is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CORE_UNDERWRITER2")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UnderWriter  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_BANK_API_ID", referencedColumnName = "BANK_API_ID")
    private Customer customer;

    .....
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "CORE_CUSTOMER")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "BANK_API_ID", nullable = false)
    private String bankApiId;

    ....
}
```

Comment: You need to show use the code where you are saving the entity. Anyway, the problem is that one of the entity involved is not managed. Probably the `Customer`. Have a look at this article: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed

Comment: @Davide I call save method of spring data JPA repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the customer id, you can try this:

```
Customer customer = entityManager.getReference(Customer.class, customerId);
underWriter.setCustomer(customer);
save(underWriter);
```

But the customer must exist in the database.
Otherwise you must first persist the customer.

Comment: I know the state of hibernate. in my case, i change the join column from the primary key to another column and I face this error .and I don't want to update Customer. CascadeType.ALl  Update Customer and UnderWriter together.

Comment: If you don't share the code it's impossible to help you. It seems from the error that Customer is not managed and therefore it doesn't let you complete the operation.

Comment: How do you get `Customer`?

Comment: before this case, I set only the id of Customer and this is ok when I save Underwriter , then I have Underwriter with reference of Customer.

Comment: I've changed my answered